# Simplifying Boolean Two Expressions

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I have these expressions

$$(A'+B'+C'+D')(A'+B'+C'+D)(A'+B+C'+D')(A'+B+C'+D)(A'+B+C+D')(A+B'+C'+D')(A+B'+C'+D)(A+B+C'+D')(A+B+C'+D)$$
$$(A'B'C D')+(A'B'C D)+(A'B C D)+(A B'C D')+(A B'C D)+(A B C D)'+(A B C D)$$

And need to simplify both. Addition means $\lor$, multiplication means $\land$ and the prime means $\neg$.

From a similar question that I asked before I know that I have to follow the laws of Boolean algebra, But I do not know how to apply them in this case that I have four variables. 
I think i can do this in wolframalpha but i really want to know how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first expression reduces to the Boolean product (logical AND) of these five factors
$$(A'+B'+C'+D')(A'+B'+C'+D) = A'+B'+C'$$
$$(A'+B+C'+D')(A'+B+C'+D) = A'+ B + C'$$
$$(A+B+C'+D')(A+B+C'+D) = A + B + C' $$
$$(A+B'+C'+D')(A+B'+C'+D) = A + B' + C' $$
$$ (A'+B+C+D') $$
Looking at the first four, we see that the Boolean product (logical AND) of all four must be $C'$ since all four factors must evaluate to true, and the only way this is possible is if $C'$ is true. So the expression reduces to:
$$ C'(A'+B+C+D') = C'(A'+B+D') $$

The second expression is the logical OR of multiple terms, but looking at the last two:
$$(A B C D)' + (A B C D) = 1$$
So the whole logical OR reduces to $1$ (or logical TRUE).

Comment: i have learned a lot but i have one question. In the second expression I understood the $$ (ABCD)′+(ABCD)=1 $$. But why the whole logical OR reduces to 1

Comment: Logical OR evaluates as true (1) iff at least one of its arguments evaluates as true. So, $x + 1 = 1$, regardless of $x$.

Comment: You're absolutely right, that was an obvious question. I want to thank you for the answer, it has helped me a lot to understand